# Where should you save your IIS files

Tags: iis, hosting

May seem like a dumb question... but where should you save your website files in IIS?

If i need to make a WCF application should I just put the code in the wwwroot folder and convert the WCF folder into application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its generally good to create a virtual directory and point it to the actual physical location, instead of putting all your files/projects in wwwroot folder